# Long Waiting Time for First Request [NODEJS]

Tags: node.js

I have built a server using nodejs. I basically send a request from the browser and the response is received from the server. Now, the first request I make from the browser, that always has a long waiting time associated with it. Waiting time for the subsequent requests from the same browser is pretty less (sometimes the difference being as high as 1 second).

I have tried debugging the issue by calculating the time taken by the server to process the request. For this, I obtain start time at the entry point and end time just before response is written back. The processing time (end time - start time) is more or less remains similar for first and subsequent requests (diff being at most 200 ms).

But still waiting time difference between the first and subsequent requests is always large (around 800-900 ms). 
Can anyone throw light on the issue?

Comment: There is cashing like browser cashing ..etc